# Sharepoint site does not appear on IIS Manager, error in open site in sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have created a site collection and then create two team sites on sharepoint server. Sites are working fine from central Admin but they are not appearing in IIS manager. Also when I try to edit a sharepoint site on sharepoint designer 2010 follwing error comes.

Unable to open website following causes:
1) the web server may not have sharepoint installed
2)The web server may be temporarily out of service
3)if you  are connecting through a proxy server the proxy settings may be incorrect
4) An error may be occured in the web server

The IIS manager only showing the follwing sites
Sharepoint 80 and sharepoint central admin

When I try to create a site on sharepoint designer following error comes:

The web site must be created on a server that is running microsoft sharpoint foundation server please chooose another location.

I have installed sharepoint server 2010, sharepoint foundation server 2010 and sharepoint designer on my pc.

thanks

Comment: maybe http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this question ?

Comment: Have you tried to recreate the web application? When creating Web app, have you checked the checkbox to create IIS Websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS Manager, you're only going to see the Web apps, the site collections and sites are wont show up (if you have another web app that isn't showing up, that's a bigger issue. I'd delete it and try to recreate it). The SharePoint Designer issue, I've had before. For me, the issue was a firewall setting. But basically if you can get to the pages with the browser, make sure you have correct permissions set for your login, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I also solved the designer issue. It is bcz of privelleges, When I login through builtin Administrator account sharepoint designer is working but when I login through my Personal/Custom  Administrator account it is not working.